# How to throw typescript error depending on two generic types and boolean

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm developing a library component that takes two generics (T, R) and as part of the input configuration, a boolean.

I'd like to enforce certain criteria on these three to throw typescript error for example if

- `someBoolean` is false,
- T is string,
- R is object.

By object I mean any non primitive type i.e. an interface.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGED2IbAOYA8AKgDTIBKAfMgN4CwAUMsgM6YC2EAQppgDYQ4IAFzIARrwFCA3I2YA3OHwCuEAPLKwAB00AKRSoiiiASlHlZDAL6NGAejtpkAdyFhkYABYoY-PpmdQPA9MZGgoTChGBGwWd3hgPgBGUQxsXEI4qCCyEGV2MWhqAF5aOVYObklBEWR4PhYIEnKDVQ1tTVF5ZGLqJMYrSxiQOLq4RIAmVKwcfAIsnORMMQArCAQwErKmCs4efhrResbmndb1TR0wLp7qGigIMGUoEFoAIi0IrWgwAE830RvJJvKw2axDWLxcZ8ADM03SczyBWgZAWIDwW3oOzYe2qQiOShOLSUbUunWQ3V6yCBbwGEJGUMSABZ4bNCEjClAyMs1htMeUcVUDvixg0msTDO0rjcqfdHs9XjQPl8fv9AcDQXTopCxokAKysjIEHnrMDc1am-nYyr7KS1Y7is4ki4da4U260B5PF7vT6Yb5QP4A6kasGDbUM3V8ABshrmaLwuXynKtzEFtsOHigqlOCmdUvJlL6WoYw1GCT4AHY45kwNl0ebeZsets0za8bU6zmJaTXTK7l6Fb6VYG1SGQWH6eXoQAOGsEDko1h1oKp3ZCu2iLuOvOSsluovjktlxl8ACc88XXKWFr5Laxbdxws72Z3FPz+-7nvlPqVfoDQbqhOJb2I4qAuG4HjeHUfgBEEITIFocAsCwEajEhKEpGgMxGgmqIruia7ph2BJirm757n27pUvIx46hhLBTNhCLssmS5XkR7bPqRRJOpR0rUdQtHgmh7gMXCzFssat5msgHH3gKXGbqKvG7r2AmHv0ImlvRyEsCyklGiaGz4fWGIKdaT7KQ65HnAWB4ejSdGRgxBqGfGBGJsuZmcVZmbbrZH5UYewnhjpLl6bG7msci17yaUD7rhmIoBT2LoaR6oVTmJenVtF0lNkmsW+Ru-mvoF-GFh6WlhSeiF6XO+XGbJCYlclL7dnx6lVVSTnaXVDEXk1MmNpaFmPqVKXlWl9lfnK3qKsq-qqsGNKauCQA)

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-enforce-configuration?file=src/app/example.component.ts)

```
interface IConfig<T, R> {
  someBoolean: boolean;
  valueOutput(value: T): R;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  template: `
    <p>I'm an example component!</p>
  `,
})
export class ExampleComponent<T, R> {
  @Input() selectOptions: T[] = [];

  @Input() config: IConfig<T, R> = {
    someBoolean: true,
    valueOutput: (v) => v as any as R, // TODO: throw if valueOutput not provided and T, R different
  };
}
```

Explicitly I'm looking to enforce the following:

```
someBoolean T   R   Allowed
false   string  string  Yes
false   string  number  No
false   string  object  No
false   number  string  No
false   number  number  Yes
false   number  object  No
false   object  string  Yes
false   object  number  Yes
false   object  object  No
true    string  string  Yes
true    string  number  No
true    string  object  No
true    number  string  No
true    number  number  Yes
true    number  object  No
true    object  string  Yes
true    object  number  Yes
true    object  object  Yes
```

I know how to do this with javascript objects but struggling to find a way with abstract generics.

#### What I've tried

I can obviously create explicit interfaces for some of these and create a union type. I don't know how to tell typescript `IConfig<T, R>` should be one of these given I get a type rather than an interface at the end. Also a little lost on how to tell typescript generic T is an interface rather than some primitive type.

```
interface IConfigBase1<T = string, R = string> {
  someBoolean: false;
}
...
interface IConfigBase10<T = object, R = object> {
  someBoolean: true;
}

type IConfigBase =
  | IConfigBase1
...
  | IConfigBase10;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[www.typescriptlang.org/play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=24&pln=5&pc=1#code/PTAEEsDsBcFMCcBmBDAxrUBJAwge0ouAOYA8AKgDSgBKAfKAN4CwAUCKBwM64C2sAQrlwAbWMkgAuUACMho8QG5W7DgDdkwgK6wA8pugAHfQAp1W2FLIBKKdSVswAX1bQAngYz9QAXlCdo8FBEAD6QmjzSCMG40gBWsKjQLu4YAAqg5FTUVADKoLAAHnCQACacMnJikKC0vswsXLwCleJSOfZqGtp6hvoSpl0WoNbe9HaszizJHlh4BMTk+UWwpeX8WUvFZaD89L5kmyvb-oGQRKwcHAD8NIerfgFBF5cvN6mZNFSyIlW0zy8cKSQWCqBD-UCWO7bMIRMENS43ahQ8owyLwcGvUDvSifCo-cR-eEAiGgYGg9FEklIwpbcoxeKJcFvD7ZUABbSEl5SbFZL4tSC0ezKMCYUAAd3E0DZAAsMIgRMJcGKgmzcPl4PBcBTUPh-KAUOBhABGKQ4fCEUgnIJUVEIPaMZ7cPiCfGSfUaTiwCjPMzdfRGaBSVQ+ehGib2HWQPUG4QAJlNcwtJCtZyo9IS0Ht9Uazv5UhQwk93vhvt0-r6oGDo0Y8Fg0E08GqDAARAZNR54G5m1Jm0bm45Jo4I7qpTGAMwJ80LW3wKgpohZx1NF3yN0Fos+wY9ANBkOgXvN8OsSPR5CGgAsk-mpBnabiGcX8KdzVd+Y9Xs35m3Far9AYtfrRtGFbdsEC7Hs+wHI8WBPUcz2EABWK8k3TRI7wZTMfAdJ9lzzd1Cw-Est3LQNKz3f86wbJsQNwDtwP3SDB2HKM4MNAA2ZCFnnG1wjRR8cxfVcpHZQjOi-Ejd2rMMWCHY8R3dQ0AHZOMtR5U1AVDMLqJdc1fNl4G0YsxL9XpSN-GtKKAls21osDXG7Bj+yYuSWIU4QAA4VJIW8HlOBcsOzPxcL0kSjMrYjTMk+gD2g2C3IATi8nzNP4oLdKE-TDM-EydzI6sKMA6ibLo+yIKc6DhSwcVJRlOUFSVFVoDVAxkE4TgXL1Fq2pNWYp1Uvy5zU-ztJw9KqjfAiwtLb8zL3VRYvkrrOHjXrr283iEB42F4FS58V3G-CNyI8TIry+h5pk5jOtazgJ1WlD7zQ0kNp2gKdMEg711E8KTty8zpNkmDFpuy97oWTTBr83bgoyr6poiv69xiy6OqlJakLB-rrV8oJobG1pMu+6aJLOysFtcpaOMx9btq2vi3tGj6CdC7Ky1O8yLsBuKluU6mIee7a8aZt0WeOnKfz3AGrrRm7PL5x7oEh3GGYE-bmYMomEYl6tka54G2sS+WMPQh8VbS4XhI1+Hfu1v8AKo4DirshyDygy6gA)

```
type B = string|number|object
type P <T, R, S extends boolean >= {
  someBoolean: S;
  valueOutput:(value: T)=> R;
}

type IConfig<T extends B, R extends B> = T extends string
    ? R extends string
        ? P<T, R, boolean>
        : never
    : T extends number
    ? R extends number
        ? P<T, R, boolean>
        : never
    : R extends object
    ? P<T, R, true>
    : P<T, R, boolean>;
```